# Displaying an alternative to an empty list in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to be able to show an alternative to an empty list, currently the following method call sets up the list, however **taskArrayList** could be empty if the call to the database has returned an empty list

```
/**
 * Setup list adapter.
 */
private void setupListAdapter() {
setListAdapter(new TaskAdapter(this, R.id.tasks_list_view,
    taskArrayList));

taskListView = getListView();
taskListView.setOnItemClickListener(new TaskClickListener());
}
```

I'm thinking that before I call this method, or at the beginning of the method adding the following check

```
if(taskArrayList.isEmpty()) {
    /*load an alternative view*/
}
```

however because my Activity is a ListActivity so it requires a ListView to be set against it, so I'm unsure of the best approach to handling the case when the list is empty.

I don't want to create a *"dummy item"* which says there are no items and add it to the ArrayList but I'm not sure of the alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add something with the idea @android:id/empty

it will be shown instead of the list when it is empty automagically!

```
 <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#FF0000"
           android:text="No data"/>
```

In the documentation they say it like this:

Optionally, your custom view can contain another view object of any type to display when the list view is empty. This "empty list" notifier must have an id "android:id/empty". Note that when an empty view is present, the list view will be hidden when there is no data to display.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html